# Drag and resize my NSPopover in menu bar app(swift)

Tags: swift, macos, resize, nspopover

I need to resize NSPopver in a menu bar app. Here is my approach:

```
override func mouseDragged(with event: NSEvent) {
    let appDelegate : AppDelegate = NSApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let originSize = appDelegate.popover.contentSize

    let currentLocation = NSWindow().mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream

    let delta_x = NSWindow().mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream.x - currentLocation.x
    let delta_y = NSWindow().mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream.y - currentLocation.y

    let newWidth = originSize.width + delta_x
    let newHeight = originSize.height + delta_y

    appDelegate.popover.contentSize = NSSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight)
}
```

Problems:

1. the NSPopover resize action cannot perform accurately.
2. I want the cursor changes to arrow when the cursor hover to the NSPopover border, how can i achieve it?

EDIT:

I have try [NSPopOver & NSViewController - Drag to resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31807226/nspopover-nsviewcontroller-drag-to-resize) solution:

[here is the effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h13z9.gif)

and here is the code that convert to the swift3 version:

```
override func mouseDragged(with event: NSEvent) {
    var currentLocation = NSEvent.mouseLocation()

    var newOrigin   = currentLocation
    let screenFrame = NSScreen.main()?.frame

    newOrigin.x     = screenFrame!.size.width - currentLocation.x
    newOrigin.y     = screenFrame!.size.height - currentLocation.y

    // Don't let window get dragged up under the menu bar
    if newOrigin.x < 260 {
        newOrigin.x = 260
    }

    if newOrigin.y < 300 {
        newOrigin.y = 300
    }


    let appDelegate : AppDelegate = NSApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.popover.contentSize = NSSize(width: newOrigin.x, height: newOrigin.y)

}
```

[This is what I expect to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRYVX.gif)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSPopOver & NSViewController - Drag to resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31807226/nspopover-nsviewcontroller-drag-to-resize)

Comment: I have tried his solution, but it didn't working, can you please help me?

Comment: Can you describe how exactly it isn't working, or how your situation differs from that one?

Comment: hello, I edited my problem, give me some advice plz.

Answer (score 0):

PopoverResize that allows a user to resize a menubar NSPopover.  It includes cursors for the edges as well.

https://github.com/dboydor/PopoverResize

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
override func mouseDragged(with event: NSEvent) {
    guard let appDelegate: AppDelegate = NSApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
    var size = appDelegate.statusItemManager.popover?.contentSize ?? CGSize.zero
    size.width += event.deltaX
    size.height += event.deltaY
    // Update popover size depend on your reference
    appDelegate.popover?.contentSize = size 
}
```